# How to add a bleed around an irregular shaped object with a full bleed photo in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, bleed

I'm trying to add a bleed to this object in Illustrator, and I'm not quite sure how to make it work. This is the item I'm trying to send to a printer:

[image]

Everything should be full bleed, including the the photograph. I was thinking of just extending the light green part using offset path, but then the photo wouldn't be full bleed. Also, how do I show the printer which part is the bleed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would ask the print shop how they would like the file to be setup. You may not have to do anything. I have worked with some print shops that want you to use a specific spot color or name for the Layer.

You will need to expand both the green background and the layer mask of the image. You can do this with Path Offset or manually move the anchor points. Anything with color does need to go past the trim/cut line.

Example of using path offset for the 2 objects. Make sure to move the bottom of the green background up to the original spot.

[image: path offset example]

Your file could look something like this.

[image: example image]

You can save a copy of your artwork as a JPG to show the print shop that there is a cutline. The copy is a JPG proof for the print shop to understand what you're trying to do. You should expect a similar image back from the print shop indicating where the cutline is.

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. How do you offset the layer mask and the green wedge shape at the same time?

Comment: @E.B. I have edited my answer with an example. Apply a path offset to both the top background image and the layer mask for the image.